# Issue in Running application on VDI

Tags: vdi, trifacta

while trying run an application, i am getting this error "Service webapp failed to start (check the service logs for more details) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/ayx105091/trifacta/./bin/service.py", line 295, in      main()   File "/home/ayx105091/trifacta/./bin/service.p"

Expecting the reason why the code is giving that error